# NameError: name 'dice1' is not defined

Tags: python, variables, undefined

It says `dice1` is not defined when I clearly said that it defines `(random.randint(min, max))`.

I tried changing the name of the variable, but it still doesn't work.

```py
import time
import random

name = input("Enter Your Name")

if name =="Name":
    pwd = input("Enter Password")

    if pwd == 'password':
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect login. Check your details and try again!")

else:
    print("Incorrect Username")     

min = 1
max = 6
score = 0
roll = "Yes"
answer = "no"

#Rolling dice

input("Roll the dice?")

while roll == "yes" or roll == "y" :
    print("Rolling......")
    dice1 = (Random.randint(min, max)) #random number between 1 and 6 as it is a dice
    print (dice1)
    time.sleep(1)
    dice2 = (Random.randint(min, max)) #another random number
    print (dice2)
    time.sleep(1)
    total1 = dice1 + dice2
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'dice1' is not defined`
```

Comment: Is the `NameError` occurred at `print(dice1)`?

Comment: can you edit your question to include the full error traceback?

Comment: `roll` is also not defined...

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

You are not assigning your input to `roll` so how is it entering your `while`?

```
roll = input("Roll the dice?")
```

What are your `min` `max` values? Maybe you didn't initialized min and max. Also you should not give `min` and `max` as variable names while they are list functions of python and you're overriding them.  I ran the following and runs just fine:

```
if name =="Name":
    pwd = input("Enter Password")
    if pwd == 'password':
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect login. Check your details and try again!")
else:
    print("Incorrect Username")
min = 1
max = 6
score = 0
roll = "Yes"
answer = "no"
roll = input("Roll the dice?")
while roll == "yes" or roll == "y" :
    print("Rolling......")
    dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
    print (dice1)
    time.sleep(1)
    dice2 = random.randint(min, max) #another random number
    print (dice2)
    time.sleep(1)
    score = dice1 + dice2
    print('Score : %d' % score)
```

Comment: @OferSadan It's a working one and I suggested that his mistake is probably in his `random` values

Comment: @KostasCharitidis if his problem was in `min` and `max`, shouldn't he get the error when calling the `random` function?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with the extract you provided. 
First, you didn't defined "roll" variable, which should be the input.
Then, you didn't defined neither min nor max.
Finally, dices will roll infinitly while your don't ask a new input at the end of the loop (but maybe that's what you want).

Please give this code a try

```py
import time
import random

roll = input("Roll the dice?")
min = 1
max = 6

while roll == "yes" or roll == "y":
    print("Rolling......")

    dice1 = (random.randint(min, max))
    print(dice1)
    time.sleep(1)

    dice2 = (random.randint(min, max))  # another random number
    print(dice2)
    time.sleep(1)

    total1 = dice1 + dice2
    roll = input("Roll the dice?")
```

Output

```py
Roll the dice?yes
Rolling......
4
4
Roll the dice?yes
Rolling......
5
2
Roll the dice?no
```

Comment: Why does my dice keep rolling even if there is time.sleep(1)

Comment: What do you mean by "dice keep rolling" ? 
The time.sleep(1) just add a 1 second delay on your program execution.
Try without it, you will see the difference.